# How to symbolicate crash report using .pdb file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, hockeyapp

I've a crash report. It's not symbolicated. I've `.pdb` file, source code and the package, is there any way to turn this stack trace to meaningful method names using `.pdb` file?

```
Exception Stack:
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x3f7d77
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0x52b4d7
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0x59ed69
MyApp.API.GetFilter()
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0x66f79f
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x368a33
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x369031
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x369b49
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x369b0f
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0x67293f
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x368a33
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x369031
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x369b49
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0x69d129
```

Comment: Does the crash report come with a minidump file (.dmp)? If it does, you can load it up in a debugger and have the debugger resolve the addresses using the .pdb files. If a minidump is not available, you could probably use the [Debug Help Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679309.aspx), and resolve the addresses manually. This is somewhat involved, though. There are probably tools available that do this for you already, but I wouldn't know of any.

Answer (score 0):

If you uploaded a .pdb along with your build. They likely do not match, ensure that your checksum and binary image UUID's match.

In order to verify if you have the correct symbols:

1. Check the id of the symbol files uploaded on the *Files* tab under *Version*
2. Check if this matches the Binary image's under crash's log
3. If these match you'll be able to see symbolicated crash reports

Comment: I would recommend contacting HockeyApp support directly: https://support.hockeyapp.net