# "The Parameter is incorrect" when creating a filter for HttpClient

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, httpclient

There is a bug bugging me a lot.

Random users of my app get this error message:

> System.ArgumentException:  The parameter is incorrect. value

in this code:

```
private HttpBaseProtocolFilter GetFilter()
{
    var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
    filter.AutomaticDecompression = true;
    filter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = HttpCacheReadBehavior.NoCache;
    filter.CacheControl.WriteBehavior = HttpCacheWriteBehavior.NoCache;
    filter.CookieUsageBehavior = HttpCookieUsageBehavior.Default;
    return filter;
}
```

What can possibly be wrong? How can I fix it? thanks.

Comment: is the error from the blog block of code?

Comment: @grepLines sorry I didn't get you

Comment: which line of code throwing error? and could you show the full stack trace?

Comment: @JaiminDave The stack trace is not human-readable, is not symbolicated. I don't know exactly which line

Comment: Surely, you have the PDB's stored in your SCM for a deployed application. Use it to turn the callstack into something human-readable.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes I have the `.pdb` files, but I didn't know I can use them. How can I? that would be great

Comment: You need to point your debugger at the PDB location. The details depend on the debugger in use.

Comment: @IInspectable I've a separate question for this same error, I'll be so thankful if you can check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045385/how-to-symbolicate-crash-report-using-pdb-file